# How to return promise response and store in external object in VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

I am trying to implement `higchart` network graph in `vue`.
its working fine with static data.When am trying to fetch data using `axios`, its not working.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      networkOptions: {
        chart: {
          type: "networkgraph",
          height: "100%",
        },
        title: {
          text: "",
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: "A Force-Directed Network Graph",
        },
        plotOptions: {
          networkgraph: {
            keys: ["from", "to"],
            layoutAlgorithm: {
              enableSimulation: true,
              integration: "euler",
              linkLength: 20,
              friction: -0.9,
            },
          },
        },
        series: [{
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            linkFormat: "",
          },
          id: "lang-tree",
          data: this.mygetCall(),
        }, ],
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    mygetCall: async function() {
      let url = `api url`;
      return await axios
        .get(url)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          let dataLink = response.data;
          let filterArray = [];
          dataLink.forEach(function(index) {
            let ref = index.referred_to.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, "").trim();
            let url = index.url.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, "").trim();
            filterArray.push([ref, url]);
          });
          console.log(filterArray);
          return filterArray;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
```

I tried with `async` and await. but its not working.If am console response from `mygetCall` function it showing result.

Comment: `I tried with async and await` - where? you can't expect help with code and not show code

Comment: Please provide some more code. What does your axios request look like?

Comment: Holy unformatted code batman! It's so hard to read... but `return filterArray;` Try updating a key in the data of the component and bind highchart to that reactive element.

Comment: @TimWickstrom I tried that also, its get updating but its not showing network graph.
I tried to change title of the chart like below. its working fine
this.networkOptions.title.text = dataLink[0].url;

but when am trying this, its not working
this.networkOptions.series.data = filterArray;

Comment: If you are binding your data correctly it sounds like HighChart is not reactive to the changes. Are you using the official HighChart Vue wrapper? If so show your code. https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-vue-wrapper/

Answer (score 0):

I formatted your javascript and looked it over, the way you had it with .then().catch() could have worked but you either would have needed another promise or a callback. Check the below it *should work:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            networkOptions: {
                chart: {
                    type: "networkgraph",
                    height: "100%",
                },
                title: {
                    text: "",
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: "A Force-Directed Network Graph",
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    networkgraph: {
                        keys: ["from", "to"],
                        layoutAlgorithm: {
                            enableSimulation: true,
                            integration: "euler",
                            linkLength: 20,
                            friction: -0.9,
                        },
                    },
                },
                series: [{
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        linkFormat: "",
                    },
                    id: "lang-tree",
                    data: this.mygetCall(),
                }, ],
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        mygetCall: function() {
            try{
                let url = `api url`;
                const response = await axios.get(url)
                if(response.data){
                    console.log(response.data);
                    let dataLink = response.data;
                    let filterArray = [];
                    dataLink.forEach(function(data) {
                        let ref = data.referred_to.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, "").trim();
                        let url = data.url.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, "").trim();
                        filterArray.push([ref, url]);
                    });
                    console.log(filterArray);
                    return filterArray;
                }
            }catch(error){
              console.log(error)
            }
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: I tried this also. not working. its console filterArray but network graph is not showing

Comment: Is filterArray in the proper format? Compare the format of when your hard coded data is parsed to when the axios response data is parsed

Comment: I tried that also, copied  filterArray from console  and assigned to data object its working fine

Comment: If your data is reactive, it is not bound correctly in the template code for HighChart. https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-vue-wrapper/

Comment: Thanks @TimWickstrom I did mistake while binding data into an object.
now its working fine thanks
this.networkOptions.series[0].data = filterArray

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve your issue and get your code working!

Answer (score 0):

```
methods: {
        mygetCall: function() {
            let filterArray = [];
      try {
        let url = `https://appup2.dev.500apps.io/v2ns/1599642495753_link`;
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        if (response.data) {
          let dataLink = response.data;
          dataLink.forEach(function (i) {  
            let url = i.url.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, "").trim();    
          });
          this.networkOptions.series[0].data = filterArray;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
        },
    },
```